# How to sum values across fields, but ignore values greater or equal to 99

Tags: field-calculator

I have a very large table where I need the sum of values across each field for each record. However, I need to skip or ignore values greater than or equal to 99.

Comment: What GIS system are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Python parser in the ArcMap field calculator, and enter this expression (the example is only for 3 fields)[untested]:

```
sum([x for x in [!f1!,!f2!,!f3!] if x < 99])
```

The expression uses Python's list comprehension to filter out all of the values from the list of inputs ([!f1!,!f2!,!f3!]) that are greater than or equal to 99. `sum` then adds up the values that remain.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using QGIS 3.10.x

This expression does the trick, independent how much fields you have:

```
eval(  array_to_string( array_filter( map_avals( attributes()), @element < 99), '+'))
```

- attributes() takes all attributes as map(key1,value1,key2,value2…)
- map_avals() returns only the values as an array
- array_filter(array, expression): Here you can filter out all the values < 99
- array_to_string(): make an array with a '+' as the delimiter
- eval(): evaluates what's inside the brackets = sum up every value